# Js Inheritance and private members

Tags: javascript, inheritance, private-members

The following code crashes due to obscure js implementation details.

```js
class A {

  constructor(x) {
    this.X = x
  }

  get X()  { throw new Error('Child should know ...')}
  set X(x) { throw new Error('Child should know ...')}

}

class B 
  extends A {
  #X

  get X()  { return this.#X }
  set X(x) { this.#X = x }
}

const b = new B(3)
```

```
  set X(x) { this.#X = x }
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot write private member #X to an object whose class did not declare it
    at B.set X [as X] ([...]/Test.js:17:22)
    at new A ([...]/Test.js:4:12)
    at new B ([...]/Test.js:12:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([...]/Test.js:20:11)
```

Is there a way to keep X private in class B without breaking inheritance logic ?

I hope someone could help me.
Regards

Comment: Why not just set `#X` in the constructor of `B`? The stucture you've shown right now doesn't make much sense - `A` would throw an error if it tries to use `X`, so it's not really useful to have `this.X = x` in there - you cannot instantiate `A` by itself.

Comment: A is abstract. But i'm agree B can do the job at construction.
Thanx for reply

Comment: In short: don't call overridable methods from the constructor - including setters.

Answer (score -1):

```
Class B extends A {
 constructor(x) {
   super(x);
   this.X = x;
 }

 get X()  { return this.X }
 set X(x) { this.X = x }
}
```

Comment: This creates infinite recursion.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.